# Continuous Integration or Publishing System

Tags: web-applications, continuous-integration, publish

I've been testing Hudson for a few days now and for PHP projects it seems ok;
What I need though is a system that will allow me to publish an SVN tag to an FTP folder without adding a pile of rubbish on the end; hudson gets overexcited and adds a pile of folders to the export.
Are their any other decent systems; it needs to be simple to use as this will eventually fall under the control of 'admins' in order to meet sox compliance (aka the man with the gun cant pull the trigger).

Basic Requirements:

- Must be free and downloadable to a server (FTP's internal only here)
- Needs to be able to interact with SVN
- Needs to be able to publish to FTP
- Needs matrix login permissions (or AD if its something that can go on IIS)
- Needs to be auditable (logging)

Tell me if im not being clear enough here; thanks.

Chris

Comment: It seems to me that all of the requirements can be met with a command line batch program or, if you prefer, a PowerShell file.

Comment: I know; I wrote a batch -> php system a while back for a one off job.
I was hoping to not have to, once again, reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it build it seems to be the solution out there; so thats just what I'll do.